# finding volume of the cone by using the dot product

Tags: vector-analysis

Vector *u* = *i* +*j* -2 *k* and *v* = 2 *i* + 3 *j* can be used to form a cone. The cone forms by rotating *u* about *v* through 360 degrees.

> Find the volume of the cone.

I drew the diagram already, I need the r and h. But I don't know how to solve this question. This question is something to do with vectors.

Comment: hint: Vcone = (1/3) pie r^2 h

Answer (score 1):

Hint: volume of cone = surface of bottom * height/3

assuming $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$

$$r_{bottom} = \cos{ \theta}*|u|$$

$$h = \sin{ \theta}*|u| = |v|$$

Comment: sorry what do you mean by sinu∠v ? or cosu∠v

Comment: the sine and cosine of the angle between $u$ and $v$ resp.

Comment: then why there is a ∠v

Comment: @harry it's actually $u \angle v$

Comment: ? u angle v ?  ??????:)